# cannot open web instpector in chrome with selenium test

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to inspect the page during an integration test, and so I have a test which I added a breakpoint in--  Once chrome launches and the test begins, the breakpoint hits, and the browser is idle..  As soon as I open the web inspector, chrome quits with the error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
  disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
```

I am using Chrome version 37.0.2062.124, and ChromeDriver version 2.10.267517

Answer (score 5):

This is intended. This is because the ChromeDriver uses the DevTools API to interact with Chrome.

The DevTools within Chrome has one major disadvantage and that is it only allows one debugger (whatever that might be, whether it's you or the driver itself) attached to it. Thus, once you open it, ChromeDriver cannot use it.

This is a limitation of Chrome -> the best you can do is get your test to a point where it fails, have your test close it's session but leave the browser open. Thus you have quit your test but effectively left your browser in the state of which the test failed.

Comment: How does one have selenium "close it's session but leave the browser open" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is about chrome issue(https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1194).

When you are running selenium program, you cannot press `F12` to open dev tools manually, or it'll throw this exception sometimes.

According to the issue list, it looks like fixed, but I still meet this bug in [ChromeDriver 2.29](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

The same problem you can [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292259/getting-selenium-error-disconnected-received-inspector-detached-event-using-c).