# getting selenium error - disconnected: received Inspector.detached event using chrome driver version 2.20.x

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When my script is trying to sendkeys for username after opening login page, I am getting disconnected: received Inspector.detached event error.

[image]

**`Console details:`**

> SaveReport FAILED: SaveSearche **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   disconnected: received Inspector.detached event**   (Session info:
>   chrome=49.0.2623.110)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145
>   (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 334 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
>   System info: host: 'jp-anal-l01', ip: '182.178.5.177', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_79' Session ID: b963137ae8a484c47efd3ac0984ea6b3 Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\ANJH1.NA\Temp\dir10584}, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   version=49.0.2623.110, takesHeapSnapshot=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
>     at **com.demoProject.loginAllTime(TestSuiteTestCases.java:99)   at
>   com.demoProject.TestCases.SaveSearch(TestSuiteTestCases.java:317)**   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   **[snip]**
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
>   **[snip]**
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   **com.demoProject.executeTestCase(TestSuiteTestCases.java:99)     at
>   com.demoProject.initialize(TestSuiteTestCases.java:56)    at
>   com.demoProject.executeModules(TestSuiteTestCases.java:142)   at
>   com.demoProject.main(TestSuiteTestCases.java:98)**

Comment: How did you get that message? Are you trying to use ChromeDriver with the Dev Tools open?

Comment: Hi Andrew, No I am not keeping any dev tools open. All my other test cases are working fine with same login script but only one test case particularly fails when it comes to login page. But yes your guess is correct, it opens login page, then shows inspect element -> console screen and fails with above error.

Comment: Thanks. Why does script try to open the console? That will break the ChromeDriver connection.

Comment: Script is not trying to open any console but automatically while execution after opening login page it is opening console and then failing. Infact it is the same login script for all other test cases which is working fine and successfully login into the application.

Comment: OK, any chance you could paste the contents of the console so we can see what happens before, i.e. perhaps what caused the logging. Also, any chance you could share the login script?

Comment: Please check below the content of console.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. Please check the console output.

Answer (score 3):

Without having the actual test code, my best guess is that `com.demoProject.loginAllTime()`, which is calling `sendKeys()`, must be sending either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, each of which will [open the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) on Windows.

As mentioned in the comments, if DevTools is opened during a WebDriver run, ChromeDriver [will be automatically disconnected](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing), producing the error:

> received Inspector.detached event

It doesn't seem to be possible to get that error any other way.

Comment: Hi Andrew. No luck. I am still trying to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is about chrome issue(https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1194).

When you are running selenium program, you cannot press `F12` to open dev tools manually, or it'll throw this exception sometimes.

According to the issue list, it looks like fixed, but I still meet this bug in [ChromeDriver 2.29](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: Hi, I am using Chrome v66 and chromedriver.exe v2.38 and still encountering this issue. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Chrome->Developer Tools are enabled.