# getting error using latest chromedriver 2.28 - disconnected: received Inspector.detached event

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, intellij-14

Seem to be getting this error waiting for popup window. As I am watching the script execute the js button executes and popup window does open but my test fails with the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: received    Inspector.detached event
(Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.20 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: '*******', ip: '*******', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520
```

Comment: not sure if this adds context to the issue I'm having or not
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292259/getting-selenium-error-disconnected-received-inspector-detached-event-using-c

Comment: are trying to open DevTools while selenium is running? You might not be able to do so since chrome only allows one debugger. what is your goal, we might be able to suggest workaround.

Comment: I am running my automation using IntelliJ.No I have nothing else open. Test was executing and I was watching it do its thing to see what the problem may be, maybe an unexpected window open but wasn't. In my scenario I submit a form for approval, we have an approval process which opens a status popup window and it goes away on its own. Its at that point where the script fails as noted above with the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is about chrome issue(https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1194).

When you are running selenium program, you cannot press `F12` to open dev tools manually, or it'll throw this exception sometimes. You can browse this [chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing) official page.

According to the issue list, it looks like fixed, but I still meet this bug in [ChromeDriver 2.29](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Chrome, I can see that your chromedriver version is 2.28 which is the most recent release and it should support Chrome v55-77, but updating Chrome might be a solution.

Comment: yeah I also have the latest chrome version.
also ran against FF with the same results.